# Android App Programming using Java

Tags: android

I am new to Android Programming and would like to build a app.Does this need to be in java or other web based technology like HTML5,CSS3,Jquery,Angular JS.I already know phonegap which can be used to develop mobile apps in Android.Is there some java way of implementing a app interface(With some links and text boxes behaving like a website).Please help.

Comment: look on the android development website

Comment: Java is the best way to develop android applications, so you can download and use ADT Bundle from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definitely need to learn Java , I would suggest you to learn xml.

**EXTRA INFORMATION :**

The officially supported integrated development environment (IDE) is Eclipse using the Android Development Tools (ADT) Plugin, though IntelliJ IDEA IDE (all editions) fully supports Android development out of the box,and NetBeans IDE also supports Android development via a plugin. Additionally, developers may use any text editor to edit Java and XML files, then use command line tools (Java Development Kit and Apache Ant are required) to create, build and debug Android applications as well as control attached Android devices